# How to make the Schedule visible in Employee module without deverloper mode in Odoo 13?

Tags: module, timezone, odoo, schedule, visible

Currently, I just see the Schedule working hours and timezone with developer mode.

So, how to make the Schedule visible without developer mode?
[image]

Comment: inherit the field and change the groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit form view and replace group section. It will be easy.

Something like:

```
<record id="view_employee_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page/div/div/group[4]" position="replace">
            <group string="Schedule">
                <field name="resource_calendar_id" required="1"/>
                <field name="tz"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I wouldn't replace the whole group but just remove the `groups` attribute instead. I upvote because the answer is correct, but will write my own :-)

Answer (score 0):

The origin form view you're inheriting resp. extending is in short:

```xml
<notebook>
    <page name="public" string="Work Information">
        <div id="o_work_employee_container"> <!-- These two div are used to position org_chart -->
            <div id="o_work_employee_main">
                <!-- ... -->
                <group string="Schedule" groups="base.group_no_one">
                    <field name="resource_calendar_id" required="1"/>
                    <field name="tz"/>
                </group>
            </div>
        </div>
    </page>
    <!-- ... --->
</notebook>
```

You could as one option just remove the `groups` attribute, which is in combination with the group `base.group_no_one` used for showing things in debug mode only:

```xml
<record id="view_employee_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='tz']/.." position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```